# Telegram API : How keep ApiState to save signIn state

Tags: java, api, telegram

I used telegram api from this source :
https://github.com/voleon/telegram-trivia-bot
But my problem is , how keep the user signed in.
Because after the App stop need user renter Mobile phone and get activation code from SMS message.
I have implemented Serializable for saving ApiState object. but this method not solved my problem.
this is the code for my ApiState :

```
package engine;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;

import org.telegram.api.TLConfig;
import org.telegram.api.TLDcOption;
import org.telegram.api.engine.storage.AbsApiState;
import org.telegram.mtproto.state.AbsMTProtoState;
import org.telegram.mtproto.state.ConnectionInfo;
import org.telegram.mtproto.state.KnownSalt;

/**
 * Created by ex3ndr on 13.01.14.
 */
public class MemoryApiState implements AbsApiState,java.io.Serializable {

    public HashMap<Integer, ConnectionInfo[]> connections = new HashMap<Integer, ConnectionInfo[]>();
    private HashMap<Integer, byte[]> keys = new HashMap<Integer, byte[]>();
    private HashMap<Integer, Boolean> isAuth = new HashMap<Integer, Boolean>();

    private int primaryDc = 1;

    public MemoryApiState(boolean isTest) {
        connections.put(1, new ConnectionInfo[]{
                new ConnectionInfo(1, 0, isTest ? "149.154.167.40" : "149.154.167.50", 443)
        });
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized int getPrimaryDc() {
        return primaryDc;
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void setPrimaryDc(int dc) {
        primaryDc = dc;
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized boolean isAuthenticated(int dcId) {
        if (isAuth.containsKey(dcId)) {
            return isAuth.get(dcId);
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void setAuthenticated(int dcId, boolean auth) {
        isAuth.put(dcId, auth);
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void updateSettings(TLConfig config) {
        connections.clear();
        HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<ConnectionInfo>> tConnections = new HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<ConnectionInfo>>();
        int id = 0;
        for (TLDcOption option : config.getDcOptions()) {
            if (!tConnections.containsKey(option.getId())) {
                tConnections.put(option.getId(), new ArrayList<ConnectionInfo>());
            }
            tConnections.get(option.getId()).add(new ConnectionInfo(id++, 0, option.getIpAddress(), option.getPort()));
        }

        for (Integer dc : tConnections.keySet()) {
            connections.put(dc, tConnections.get(dc).toArray(new ConnectionInfo[0]));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized byte[] getAuthKey(int dcId) {
        return keys.get(dcId);
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void putAuthKey(int dcId, byte[] key) {
        keys.put(dcId, key);
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized ConnectionInfo[] getAvailableConnections(int dcId) {
        if (!connections.containsKey(dcId)) {
            return new ConnectionInfo[0];
        }

        return connections.get(dcId);
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized AbsMTProtoState getMtProtoState(final int dcId) {
        return new AbsMTProtoState() {
            private KnownSalt[] knownSalts = new KnownSalt[0];

            @Override
            public byte[] getAuthKey() {
                return MemoryApiState.this.getAuthKey(dcId);
            }

            @Override
            public ConnectionInfo[] getAvailableConnections() {
                return MemoryApiState.this.getAvailableConnections(dcId);
            }

            @Override
            public KnownSalt[] readKnownSalts() {
                return knownSalts;
            }

            @Override
            protected void writeKnownSalts(KnownSalt[] salts) {
                knownSalts = salts;
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void resetAuth() {
        isAuth.clear();
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void reset() {
        isAuth.clear();
        keys.clear();
    }

    public void saveObject()
    {
        try
        {
           FileOutputStream fileOut =
           new FileOutputStream("apistate3.tmp");
           ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);
           out.writeObject(this);
           out.close();
           fileOut.close();
           System.out.printf("Serialized data is saved");
        }catch(IOException i)
        {
            i.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public MemoryApiState readObject()
    {
        try
        {
           FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream("apistate3.tmp");
           ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);
           MemoryApiState obj = (MemoryApiState) in.readObject();
           in.close();
           fileIn.close();
           return obj;
        }catch(IOException i)
        {
           i.printStackTrace();
           return null;
        }catch(ClassNotFoundException c)
        {
           System.out.println("Employee class not found");
           c.printStackTrace();
           return null;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: سلام برادر این مشکل شما حل شد ؟ تونستی حلش کنی؟

Comment: Yes , HamidReza answer's solved my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hi : you can save state in file with any extension as follow:

```
private void SaveState(String fileName, MemoryApiState mas)
{

  try     
    {
    FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(fileName + ".sta");
        ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);
        out.writeObject(mas);
        out.close();
        fileOut.close();
    }
        catch (IOException i)
         {
           i.printStackTrace();
         }
}
```

and than load saved state from file as follow :

```
private MemoryApiState LoadState(String fileName)
 {
    try
        {


          FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream(fileName + ".sta");
          ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);
          MemoryApiState mas = (MemoryApiState)in.readObject();
          in.close();
          fileIn.close();

         return mas;
        }
    catch (IOException i)
        {
          return null;
        }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException c)
        {         
          c.printStackTrace();
        }
            return null;
 }
```

Comment: i am getting "java.io.NotSerializableException: org.telegram.mtproto.state.ConnectionInfo" by this method how can i fix this ?

Comment: you should add ( implements Serializable )  expression to org.telegram.mtproto.state.ConnectionInfo class and derived class