# Save Telegram state permanently

Tags: java, android, telegram

I want to store the state of a custom telegram messaging app, such that the user does not have to reregister (request authcode etc.).

Referring [Telegram API : How keep ApiState to save signIn state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30528753/telegram-api-how-keep-apistate-to-save-signin-state) I have currently following implementation:

```
...
apiState = loadState(apiStateFile + ".tmp");
...
private MemoryApiState loadState(String fileName) {
    try {
        FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream(fileName);
        ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);
        MemoryApiState mas = (MemoryApiState) in.readObject();
        in.close();
        fileIn.close();

        return mas;
    } catch (IOException i) {
        return null;
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException c) {
        c.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

and on each state change I call

```
private void saveState(String fileName, MemoryApiState mas) {

    try {
        FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
        ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);
        out.writeObject(mas);
        out.close();
        fileOut.close();
    } catch (IOException i) {
        i.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

However, even though apiState is not null and it is obviously connected to Telegrams' server (I see all the output on the console, coming from the servers), the client ID is, for example, 0. This means, the registration is not stored.

I see the file written in the filesystem with the serialized object and it does not give me any output if the object is saved or loaded.

The implementation for MemoryApiState is from Telegram: https://github.com/rubenlagus/TelegramApi/blob/51713e9b6eb9e0ae0d4bbbe3d4deffff9b7f01e4/src/main/java/org/telegram/bot/kernel/engine/MemoryApiState.java